# Can't get opengl/glfw to work with vs2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, setup-project

Whenever I try to make a call from glfw I get a linking error,the header files are all setup so don't worry about them.So the problem is that VS doesn't seem to find the .lib files, I have tried to give the full path to glfw3.lib and I also have tried with both .lib files (glfw3.lib,glfw3dll.lib) but without success.. I also have glew and sfml incase I should mention that.

Screenshots from the setup: http://imgur.com/WlrGTHq&XIKFdeE&seDfSGP
The error I'm receiving is "LNK2019"

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshots it looks like you're trying to link the x64 GLWF library in the Win32 configuration, when I reproduce that setup I am also greeted by a number of `error LNK2019`s.

There should also have been a warning that could have tipped you off:

```
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glfwShowWindow
referenced in function _main

D:\Dev\glfw-3.1.2.bin.WIN64\lib-vc2015\glfw3.lib : warning LNK4272: 
library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'
```

If I build the x64 configuration, it links and runs fine.

Comment: When I change to x64 VS complains about that glew32.lib is x86 and I'm trying to build x64 so do I need some glew64.lib? because I can't find one.

Comment: In the pre-compiled binaries available on the [GLEW page](http://glew.sourceforge.net/), both are included under `lib/Release/Win32/` and `lib/Release/x64/`. These match the VS platform name, so you can simply add `lib/Release/$(Platform)/` as the library directory.

Comment: There are `glew32.lib` and `glew32s.lib`, though - the former is the import library for `glew32.dll` from `bin/Release/$(Platform)/`, the latter the self-contained static library.

Comment: The problem you're having with the glew libraries may be 1) mixing release and debug builds which link different versions of the runtime libraries, 2) the pre-compiled glew binaries were built with VS2013. You may have to build glew from source with VS2015 and match your compiler options, or try this [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/glew.v140/1.12.0/).

Comment: Now seems like I'm getting this sorted out but now it says "missing glew32.dll", I tried to solve this by going into the bin folder of the glew folder and finding the glew32.dll and placing it next to the .libs but no results even tried restarting VS.

Comment: Also tried downloading the nuget GLEW package but I don't understand how I should use it or access it/Import it.

Comment: When you start your application from VS, it's not executed in the output directory, but usually in the project directory. Check the Working Directory setting under Debugging - the DLL must be discoverable from *there*.

Comment: Actually, try this NuGet package: [NupenGL Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/nupengl.core/0.1.0/), it includes GLEW and GLFW, and seems to work entirely automagically :)

Comment: Thanks alot! now i don't have any errors anymore thats exactly what I needed!